# Cast from '[PFObject]' to unrelated type 'int' always fails [Swift]

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm trying to put into a variable my PFObject (I'm using Parse):

```
func retrieveScore() {


    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Score")


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in


        for varScore in objects! {
            let scoreExtract:Int? = (varScore as? [PFObject]) as? Int
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives to me this error: "Cast from '[PFObject]' to unrelated type 'int' always fails.

How can I extract the object into a variable? I need an array?

thank you.

Comment: What vaeScore holds?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is first converting `varScore` to an `Array` of `PFObject` and then converting that `Array` to an `Int`. How can you convert an `Array` to `Int`?

If objects contains `Array` of `PFObject` then,

```
func retrieveScore() {
   var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Score")
   query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

      for varScore in objects! {
          let score = varScore as? PFObject
          let youeIntPropertyValue = score.someIntProperty// a property in Score class/struct.
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Admit89 I can't understand what I have to write here: let youeIntPropertyValue = score.someIntProperty

Comment: I don't know the integer property inside the Score class. From reader's point of view i just wrote. You need to replace it with your Int property.

Comment: can you do an example of what an Int property should be? Score class contain Int value! can you please do me an example by write some codeline?

Comment: Can you post your Score class here?

Comment: var playerScore:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Score")
playerScore["Player1"] = 1
playerScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { ...

Comment: @Admit89 you mean that class right? You have enough information?

Comment: No, from your above code may be you need to do like score["Player1"] or score.Player1

Comment: let youeIntPropertyValue = score["Player1"] 

or

let youeIntPropertyValue = score.Player1